# Date query in MongoDb TimeZone issue

Tags: java, mongodb, date

Hi I am getting below problem while implementing the logic for removing 1 month old documents from mongoDB.
Below is code and output…

```
currDate = new Date();   // value is : Tue Nov 26 15:22:10 **EST** 2013
Calendar calDate = Calendar.getInstance();  
calDate.setTime(new Date());  
calDate.add(Calendar.MONTH,-1);               
currDateMinusOneMonth =  calDate.getTime(); // value is : Sat Oct 26 15:22:10 **EDT** 2013                            

Criteria c1 = Criteria.where("publishDate").lt(currDateMinusOneMonth);                    
Query query = new Query(c1);        
logger.info("Query to find 1 month old documents: " + query.toString()); --> 
{"publishDate" : { "$lt" : { "$date" : "2013-10-26T**19**:22:10.571Z"}}}
```

Somehow it adds 4 hours to the Time in the Query. Not sure why this is happening. How can we avoid this?

When I replace Criteria as Below

```
Criteria c1 = Criteria.where("publishDate").lt(**currDate**);
```

it adds 5 hours instead of 4 hours. Guess because currDate value is in EST and not EDT.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It adds 4 hours because that date is showing in UTC, which is 4 hours ahead of EDT (which was the correct time zone a month ago). I don't think there is a problem here.

Comment: So it will run the query as expected right? And I need not worry that the date is 4 hours off while executing?

Comment: Yes, it should adjust them all to compare from the same timezone so it should be "correct". Does it really matter, though? I mean, the definition of "one month ago" seems kind of subjective anyway (some months have 31 days, others have 28). If you get the documents to remove an hour or four too early/late, is that going to damage your business process?

Comment: No in this case, it is fine. I was just curious to find out in case it there is time critical application. But this helped a lot. Now I can try out for something that is critical. Thanks.